# D3.js: misplaced labels

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm newbie with d3.js and I'm trying to create a half donut chart and put labels in the middle of each arc.

I have made a developmen with CodeSandbox which works fine. The labels are placed correctly but when I bring that code to the code of my web application. The code is exactly the same. These labels are misplaced and I don't know why :(

The only difference between both codes is that the code of the first screen cap is inside a "Col" of Bootstrap and the second not as you can see in the CodeSandBox.

Here you can see a screencap of the half donut chart in my web application:

[image]

As you can see the labels of each arch and the labels of the right legend are misplaced when the same code in CodeSandbox works fine placing all the labels in the right place. As you can see in this screencap:

[image]

Why happen that? How can I make that labels would be placed right in both developments?

You can see all the code of my Half Donut Chart in this CodeSandoox

[image: Edit Half Donut Chart]

**Edit I:**

I have created a trace in my code to know the values depending of the web browser.

Here is the code where I center the labels to the arcs:

```
//We center the text inside the arc
arcs
  .append("svg:text")
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    var textWidth = getTextWidth(
      (d.value.toFixed(2) + "%").toString(),
      "Roboto"
    );
    console.log(
      "d.value: " +
        d.value +
        " textWidth: " +
        textWidth +
        " arc.centroid(d)[0]: " +
        arc.centroid(d)[0]
    );
    return (
      "translate(" +
      (arc.centroid(d)[0] - textWidth) +
      "," +
      arc.centroid(d)[1] +
      ")"
    );
  })
  .attr("class", "label-half-donut")
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
    // are we past the center?
    return (d.endAngle + d.startAngle) / 2 > Math.PI ? "end" : "start";
  })
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.value.toFixed(2) + "%";
  });
```

You can find all the code in CodeSandBox button.

The code of CodeSandBox I run it with Chrome and I've got this graphic

[image]

And the values returned in Chrome are:

```
d.value: 13.13 textWidth: 33.916015625 arc.centroid(d)[0]: -86.00117936328948
```

The tags which build the arc is this:

```
<g class="slice">
    <path fill="#17A2B8" d="M-124.99275003141527,-1.3462687637091173A125,125,0,0,1,-116.9896333088247,-44.02755612416768L-47.07429579530035,-16.85261627690394A50,50,0,0,0,-49.98187231803007,-1.3462687637091153Z"></path>
    <text transform="translate(-119.91719498828948,-16.12597743156403)" class="label-half-donut" dy=".35em" text-anchor="start">13.13%</text>
</g>
```

When I run the same code in my website with Firefox I've got this graphic:

[image]

The values returned are:

```
d.value: 13.13 textWidth: 38.150001525878906 arc.centroid(d)[0]: -86.00117936328948
```

And the tag which build the arc is:

```
<g class="slice">
    <path fill="#17A2B8" d="M-124.99275003141527,-1.3462687637091173A125,125,0,0,1,-116.9896333088247,-44.02755612416768L-47.07429579530035,-16.85261627690394A50,50,0,0,0,-49.98187231803007,-1.3462687637091153Z"></path>
    <text transform="translate(-124.15118088916839,-16.12597743156403)" class="label-half-donut" dy=".35em" text-anchor="start">13.13%</text>
</g>
```

The difference between both are that textWidth returned for the same value "13.13" returns different values and the x of translate function are differents because is calculated using this value.

How is that possible? Am I doing something wrong?

**Edit II:**

After the solution proposed by @Coola. This works for Firefox but not for Chrome :(

**Firefox**

[image]

**Chrome**

[image]

The value of textWidth is still different depending if I'm using Firefox or Chrome.

**Firefox**

```
d.value: 13.13 textWidth: 38.150001525878906 arc.centroid(d)[0]     -86.00117936328948
d.value: 59.7 textWidth: 38.150001525878906 arc.centroid(d)[0]: -33.49019847517988 
d.value: 23.88 textWidth: 38.150001525878906 arc.centroid(d)[0]: 59.22461768695275 
d.value: 17.91 textWidth: 38.150001525878906 arc.centroid(d)[0]: 84.79723004914864
```

**Chrome**

```
d.value: 13.13 textWidth: 33.916015625 arc.centroid(d)[0]: -86.00117936328948
d.value: 59.7 textWidth: 33.916015625 arc.centroid(d)[0]: -33.49019847517988
d.value: 23.88 textWidth: 33.916015625 arc.centroid(d)[0]: 59.22461768695275
d.value: 17.91 textWidth: 33.916015625 arc.centroid(d)[0]: 84.79723004914864
```

Comment: Hello @JoseCarlos, It would be really helpful, if you would share web application link or some other platform (try with jsfiddle or stackblitz) where this error will come and we can able to see what exactly is happening.

Comment: Did you use the DOM inspector of your web browser to check the applied CSS styles of the `text` nodes, and their computed positions?

Comment: Hi @Mehdi!!! I'm going to check it and tell you something about that!!! Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: Hi @Mehdi!!! I have updated my original post with some values. Also, I have checked that my web application run it in Chrome returns the same graphic and values that my web application run it in Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your translate for your text was not being calculated properly. Your `x` value on the transform should be `arc.centroid(d)[0] - textWidth / 2`.

So your transform should be like:

```
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        var textWidth = getTextWidth(
          (d.value.toFixed(2) + "%").toString(),
          "Roboto"
        );
        console.log(
          "d.value: " +
            d.value +
            " textWidth: " +
            textWidth +
            " arc.centroid(d)[0]: " +
            arc.centroid(d)[0]
        );
        let x = arc.centroid(d)[0] - textWidth / 2;
        let y = arc.centroid(d)[1];
        return "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")";
      })
```

[The working codesandbox is here](https://codesandbox.io/s/half-donut-chart-ld6bi).

Firefox Developer Edition v75.0b:

[image: Screenshot of Firefox Codesandbox]

Chrome v80.0.3987.149: 
[image]

**Update**

After discussion with the OP, they still had the problem in their workspace. We investigated a bit more and discovered that the issue was caused by inherited styles for the font-family, while the calculation of the `textWidth` was being done for `Roboto` font-family. To fix this we added the style as `.style("font-family", "'Roboto', sans-serif")` to the label text. This fixed the issue and the working [codesandbox is here](https://codesandbox.io/s/half-donut-chart-ld6bi).

Comment: It works only in Firefox. With Chrome doesn't work. Sincerelly, I don't know what happen :(. I'm going to update my original post with the result.

Comment: Hi Jose. For me it works in both chrome and firefox. I have added screenshots above. So I am unable to reproduce your issue. Is the issue only appearing in your app now or is it also in the codesandbox?

Comment: Hi @Coola!!!  To me works fine your solution in Firefox and Chrome, but in my app, textWidth has differente values in Chrome and Firefox and I don't know why that happen?

Comment: Well it is difficult to diagnose something specific in your application unless you can share it in some way? One thing you can try is just to change the class on the text just to make sure that it is not being edited by some other code on the page. FYI I checked the console and I do get different values in both chrome and firefox in the codesandbox but it doesn't seem to have an effect on the rendering.

Comment: One thing that could be happening is that the style font-family is being inherited for your labels. However, you calculate that for just Roboto. Try applying `.style("font-family", "'Roboto', sans-serif")` to your text using d3js. Check this https://codesandbox.io/s/half-donut-chart-ld6bi

Comment: OMG!!! It works!!! Thank you very much for your effort and help!!!!

Comment: Ha... Happy that solved it. Stay safe and happy coding. Will edit my answer accordingly.